# How to write test with Jest for getData() using module.exports for testing but requires ESM export syntax for React/Gatsby. Json file cannot parse

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, gatsby, import-module

Below are my functions. I need these in my React/Gatsby app therefore I export it with ESM export syntax. but I cannot use it for testing.

problem to: see printscreen.. Jest doesn't seem to like the Json file? [image]

```js
import gameOfThrones from "../data/gameOfThrones.json";

const getGameOfThronesData = ()=> {
    console.log(gameOfThrones.gameOfThrones.episodes)
}
    
const getEpisodesPerSeason = (season)=> gameOfThrones.gameOfThrones.episodes.filter(episode=> episode.season === season)
const getEpisodeData = (episodeId)=> gameOfThrones.gameOfThrones.episodes.find(episode=> episode.id === episodeId)
const getNextEpisode = episodeId => null
const getPrevEpisode = episodeId => null
    
export {getGameOfThronesData, getEpisodesPerSeason, getEpisodeData, getNextEpisode, getPrevEpisode}
    
// module.exports = {
//     getGameOfThronesData, getEpisodesPerSeason, getEpisodeData, getNextEpisode, getPrevEpisode
// };
```

Comment: Jest is misconfigured. It's supposed to transpile ESM. Did you check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/unit-testing/ ? What is exactly your current Jest config?

Comment: I installed Jest as a devDependancy, thats it.

Comment: It's all working after following the gatsby setup for unit testing

Comment: @Emma You can (and should!) answer your own question here so others with the same question can find and benefit from your research and solution. After you answer you'll need to wait 48hrs to accept your own answer, but once that time has passed you should feel welcome to accept your answer too.

Comment: @coreyward. It seems logical to me to accept the answer of Estus Flask. But I see that that is nog an option for me..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following setup on this page does the trick https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/unit-testing/